# change content of a remote file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to change content of `chatt.php` file on server, using ajax procedure.

```
$("#btnsend").click(function(){
    var a = $("#write").val();
    console.log(a); // that's ok
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: a,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert("323");
        }
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
$a = $_POST["a"];
$b = "chapters/chatt.php");

file_put_contents($b, $a);
```

There is no alert, `chatt.php` is not changed, console is empty.

Any help?

Comment: What does your javascript console say?

Comment: Check access and error logs on the server

Comment: U r getting undefined index use like that data: "a="+a,

Comment: the closing parens on line `$b` is a syntax error...

Comment: @chilinut yes OP also get the parse error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add php `error_reporting()`.

**[Error Reporting Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)**

In php you are getting the Undefined index notice for `$_POST['a']`. You need to pass a from ajax as:

**Modified code**:

```
$("#btnsend").click(function(){ 
var a = $("#write").val(); 
console.log(a); // that's ok 
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: "ajax.php", 
data: "a="+a, 
dataType: "json", 
success: function () { 
alert("323"); 
} }); 
});
```

As my other mate mentioned in comments if you solve this issue you will face an another issue like Parse error for this line:

```
$b = "chapters/chatt.php"); // unexpected bracket
```

**Side note**:

Keep in mind `error_reporting()` is only for development not for productions.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sending correct data, try:

```
data: {a: a}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never bothered naming your data parameter, so `$_POST['a']` doesn't exist. PHP expects `key=value` for POST data, and you're sending over a bare `value`.

Try

```
  data: { a: a}
          ^--key
             ^---value
```

instead.

And note that you're opening your server up to a total remote compromise. If this `chatt.php` is inside your site's document root, a malicious user can use your code to write **ANY** php code they want to the file, and your server will happily execute it for them.

Comment: Nice explanation marc